# Using python atlassian api to get the jira data

Tags: python, jira

I am using below code to get the jira data via atlassian API : https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/

Code snippet is as below :

```
from atlassian import Jira

jira_token = "*************"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Using atlassian jira connector")
    jira = Jira(url="https://abc.atlassian.net/", token=jira_token)
    data = jira.get_issue(issue_id_or_key="JIRA-15887")
    print(data)
```

when running the code i am getting below error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\srivastu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\atlassian_jira_connector.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = jira.get_issue(issue_id_or_key="PERFORMA-15887")
  File "C:\Users\srivastu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\atlassian\jira.py", line 1006, in get_issue
    return self.get(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\srivastu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 285, in get
    response = self.request(
  File "C:\Users\srivastu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 257, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "C:\Users\srivastu\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\atlassian\rest_client.py", line 483, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
```

Problem is JIRA is using in SSO authentication there is no username and password set up so thats why i have generated API token and using it to connect via python script .

But its not working in, any leads on this how to connect in.

Thanks

Comment: username is your email, try adding that.